# How can I clear my Angular reactive form?

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms

I have a mat-radio-group inside my form and I would like to clear the radio button so that nothing is selected for each new question in my quiz app. How do I go about doing this? Here's how my form looks:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <ol class="form-group">
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="answer" name="answer" (change)="radioChange($event.value)"
  (click)="question.selectedOption = option">
      <div class="radio-options" *ngFor="let option of question.options">
        <mat-radio-button class="option" [value]="option.optionValue" disableRipple="true"
          [checked]="question.selectedOption == option"
          [ngClass]="{'is-correct': isCorrect(option.optionValue),
                  'is-incorrect': isIncorrect(option.optionValue)}">
          <li>{{ option.optionText }}</li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reset Angular Reactive Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749355/how-can-i-reset-angular-reactive-form)

Comment: why are you using ngForm and formgroup together? remove ngForm if you are planning to use reactive forms.

Answer (score 6):

You can reset your form:

```
reset() {
    this.myForm.reset();
  }
```

OR

like @miselking mentioned: Just reset specific control (in this case "radio button"). Something like `this.myForm.get('radioButtonControl').reset()`

Comment: Or just reset specific control (in this case "radio button"). Something like `this.myForm.get('radioButtonControl').reset()`

Comment: tried this.quizForm.reset() and it didn't seem to work. Also trying this.quizForm.get('answer').reset() and am getting an error: error TS2339: Property 'get' does not exist on type 'NgForm'.

Comment: @multiv123, How are the form controls defined in your code? Please check the name and share the code if possible for others to take alook and answer.

Comment: <form #quizForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(quizForm.value)">
  <ol class="form-group">
    <mat-radio-group formControlName="answer" name="answer" (change)="radioChange($event.value)"
      (click)="question.selectedOption = option">
      <div class="radio-options" *ngFor="let option of question.options">
        <mat-radio-button class="option" [value]="option.optionValue" disableRipple="true"
          [checked]="question.selectedOption == option"
          [ngClass]=...

Comment: you can also use this:`this.myForm.reset({answer: null});`

Comment: I tried using this, doesn't seem to work. Please could you take a look at my Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-quiz-app

Comment: I do not see you submitting the form in your code. Look at this simpler example of how it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slemqj-7s3tbw?file=app/radio-overview-example.html

Comment: I'm using a next button in a different component and having trouble with the component-component communication. I tried adding the code for resetting but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest and cleanest way to clear forms as well as their error states (dirty, pristine etc)

```
this.formName.reset();
```

for more info on forms readout [here](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

**OR**

Just reset specific control (in this case "radio button")

```
this.myForm.get('radioButtonControl').reset()
```